# how to attach a data file over the call of attachment from another app

Tags: android, android-intent, methods

i have an application which send image data to different applications via simple share intent.
what i want to know is that, if i want to receive a call function for image sharing from another application... what should i do.?

Let suppose i have my package, named:

```
com.jai.test
```

but i want a calling function from another package of different application
Let suppose:

```
com.xxx.noob
```

what should i implement, any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be really great if a framework supported this feature. It would really promote Open Source beyond imagination. But alas! Android does not support this.

Comment: well i disagree with your answer because i think you misjudge the question of mine.